# "source" to set PATH to bitbake with shell=True having no effect in Python

Tags: python, bash, shell, bitbake

Below is the code in shell script

```
source /proj/common/tools/repo/etc/profile.d/repo.sh
repo project init $branch
repo project sync
source poky/fnc-init-build-env build
bitbake -g $image
```

I am trying to convert shell script into python script

```
a = subprocess.call("source /proj/common/tools/repo/etc/profile.d/repo.sh", shell=True)
b = subprocess.call("repo project init " + branch, shell=True)
b2 = subprocess.call("repo project sync", shell=True)
c = subprocess.call("source poky/fnc-init-build-env build", shell=True)
os.chdir("poky/build")
d = subprocess.call("bitbake -g " + image, shell=True)
```

But i am getting the following error

```
/bin/sh: bitbake: command not found
```

How to resolve this in python ?

Comment: have you installed "bitbake"?

Comment: Or otherwise your installation is in a directory other than in $PATH

Comment: `subprocess.call("bitbake -g " + image, shell=True)` is actually much buggier than the shell you replaced it from. If `image='$(touch /tmp/evil).jpg'` in shell, that would be harmless; in your Python, it would create an unwanted file (or run any other command embedded in the filename). Use `shell=False` if you care *at all* about security or correctness.

Comment: ...that said, the **immediate** concern is that the shell in which you `source repo.sh` is a completely different shell from the one in which you later call `bitbake -g`.

Comment: ...so, if `bitbake` only becomes available after the above (`source`, `repo`, etc) commands are run in the same shell, splitting those commands across multiple `subprocess.call()`s will never work.

Answer (score 0):

you must add bitbake to path:

```
set Path=%path%;PathOfBitbake
```

run it on Command prompt of Windows then retry

Comment: Since the OP is using bash-only shell commands, it appears unlikely that their platform is Windows.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy He Didn't Specified if his System is Windows or Linux

Comment: Yes, but the `source` command is a bashism (and the question is tagged bash). Bash is not what `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)` uses on Windows. Thus, absent any explicit specification, it is a likely presumption that the OP is not on Windows.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Its Not True , I Tried subprocess.Popen() and subprocess.call() it gave me the same Result ( I Am Running that On Windows)

Comment: What same result? Of *course* you'll get `bitbake: command not found`. You couldn't have tried running `source /proj/common/tools/repo/etc/profile.d/repo.sh`, since nobody but the OP has that `repo.sh` file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy wait i will install bitbake then i will try it by my self For see what it will do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170539/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-skiller-dz).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you run `subprocess.call(something, shell=True)` several times and assume that the variables set in the first call are present in the later calls, which use shells independend from the earlier calls.

I would put the commands in a shell script and then run it with a single `subprocess.call` command. There seems to be no real point in converting it line by line into python by just running shell commands with the `subprocess` module.

When `repo` and `bitbake` are python programs there could be a point to import the relevant modules from them and run the corresponding python functions instead of the shell commands provided by their main method.

Answer (score 0):

When using `shell=True`, the first list element is a script to run, and subsequent arguments are passed to that script.

Each `subprocess.Popen()` invocation *starts a single shell*; state configured in one isn't carried through to others, so the `source` command is useless unless *you run the commands that depend on it within the same invocation*.

```
script='''
branch=$1; shift  # pop first argument off the list, assign to variable named branch
source /proj/common/tools/repo/etc/profile.d/repo.sh || exit
repo project init "$branch" || exit
repo project sync || exit
source poky/fnc-init-build-env build || exit
exec "$@"  # use remaining arguments to form our command to run
'''

subprocess.call([
    "bash", "-c", script,    # start bash, explicitly: /bin/sh does not support "source"
    "_",                     # becomes $0 inside the shell
    branch,                  # becomes $1, which is assigned to branch and shifted off
    "bitbake", "-g", image   # these arguments become "$@" after the shift
])
```

Note the `|| exit`s -- you should generally have those on any command where you don't *explicitly intend* to ignore failures.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Duffy. Its working fine but I need it to be in python script.

Comment: I am using "linux machine & python version is 2.7" @Charles_Duffy

Comment: @PuneethKumar, this *is* Python. You can't use `source` without a bash shell, so it's absolutely necessary that you embed a shell script inside your Python script unless you rewrite your Python to do everything the scripts you're `source`ing do internally. And obviously, we can't tell you how to do that unless you extend the question to actually include the text of those scripts.

Comment: @PuneethKumar, ...anyhow, if you wanted to make your original code pure Python, with no shell dependencies, you couldn't use `shell=True`. Since the question includes `shell=True`, clearly calling a shell interpreter from your Python code is acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the path to 'bitbake', so it is found from your python script.

```
sys.path.append(your_path_there)
```

Comment: `sys.path` refers to the PYTHONPATH, not to the PATH used to find executables.